# What version of dill should I be using when running Apache Beam v 2.2.5 with Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dill

I am attempting to run a Dataflow job using Apache Beam v 2.25 and Python 3.7. Everything runs ok when using DirectRunner, but the job errors out when it attempts to invoke a function form another private Python module.

The error is

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_create_code' on <module 'dill._dill' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py'>
```

My setup file looks like this:

```
setup(
name="Rich Profile and Activiation reports",
version="0.1",
description="Scripts for reports",
author="Kim Merino",
install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
include_package_data=True,
package_data={"": ["*.json"]},
```

)

My question is what version of dill should I be using for Apache Beam v. 2.25? I am currently using Dill v 0.3.3

I have an external dependency that required dill in order to work

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set `--save_main_session=True` when running the pipeline?

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how_do_i_handle_nameerrors

Comment: I set `save_main_session=True` like so with no luck:
`def run(pipeline, save_main_session=True):`

I even commented out any import statements to any other external modules and still receive the error `AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_create_code' on <module 'dill._dill' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py'>`

Comment: Can you please provide some more code on how you run the pipeline? This parameter should be send inside the options for the pipeline.

Comment: My Beam code looks like this:

`def run(pipeline, save_main_session=True):`
    `p = pipeline`
     `p.run().wait_until_finish()`

I run it with `python main.py`

Comment: Here is how to send that param to the pipeline https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount_minimal.py#L105. If you already doing this, then it can be a problem with how you set up dependencies for the pipeline or, you can try importing the library rigth before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the same error message just now. What solved it was to make sure that I was using a Python virtual environment dedicated to my Beam/Dataflow code, in other words something like:

```
cd [code dir]
python -m venv env
source ./env/bin/activate
pip install apache-beam[gcp]
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Previously I was lazily using my global copy of Python 3. I'm not entirely sure why this fixed it, but I might have been using an incompatible version of `dill` (which is just a pickling-related library used by Beam).

When you either package your Beam code as a Classic Template or invoke Dataflow directly from your laptop, in either case, your code ends up getting pickled and sent to Dataflow. So if you are using a Python installation with an incompatible module, that can cause issues.

And of course in any case, it's a best practice to have a virtual environment for your repo, so this can narrow down the universe of possible issues.

Comment: I ended up removing the external dependency that needed dill to work. I now have a simple `requirements.txt` file that's just `apache-beam[gcp]`. My code was requiring Dill to work, but keeping the requirements file super simple did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I removed the external dependency and kept the requirements to a minimum